# Возможно-ли наложить эмодзи на изображение через graphicsmagick?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я пытался наложить эмодзи с помощью drawText(), использовал шрифт NotoEmoji-Regular (также пробовал NotoColorEmoji и AppleColorEmoji), в качестве текста использовал unicode. Но вместо эмодзи накладывается ▯

```js
gm('oo9.png')
.font('NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf', 20)
.drawText(40, 40, '\uF3E2')
.write('oo8.png', function (err) {
  (err) ? console.log(err) : console.log('+')
})
```

Comment: `\uF3E2` - что это за символ?

Comment: Я решил это через наложение изображения (draw('image Over [положение x,y] [размер x,x] [имя файла.формат]')) Для наложения скачал эмодзи как изображение без фона